# Online Learning: Different User Roles Different Fields

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key, table

I'm trying to build an online learning system ( similar to Udemy ), where users have different types ( or roles ).

For now "roles" are : **students** , **instructors**  and **admins** ,and it may increase in the future.Where each role has its own permissions.

A user can have 1 role or more, so
a user can be a student of some course and an instructor of ( another course )

see below:

[image]

**the problem :**
now, each role may have different fields ,for example:
an **instructor** role has a unique field like "biography" which no any of the other user roles has.

how can this be accomplished with this database design , I was thiking of creating tables like:

```
**instructors_users Table**
user_id
some unique fields for instructors role

**students_users Table**
user_id
some unique fields for students role
```

Is this right ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Table Inheritance

If you don't mind nulls, use Single Table Inheritance. Add a "type" column, then add nullable columns for the different types, and check constraints for integrity

https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html

if you do mind nulls, add one table per subtype and join to super type with a foreign key

https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html

ORMs like [Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html) can automate this for you

Answer (score -1):

Add a table called field which has all fileds (biography, mathematics..)

```
**field Table**
id
name_fields
```

And another table called user_field_role

```
**user_field_role table**
user_id
field_id
role_id
```

if you want to make a user X instructor of biography then in user_field_role you put the user_id and biography id and instroctor id

Comment: EAV is always a bad idea

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan How can it be always a bad idea.Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/876459/5671807 and this http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1619660-OTLT-EAV-design-why-do-people-hate-it

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan why is this a bad idea ? I do like it and its more dynamic ... can you explain ?

Comment: @rook99, there are situations where it might be appropriate with EAV, but in most situations, EAV will cause both performance issues as well as difficulties expressing even trivial logic.